# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found

Tags: r, dataframe, rpart

I cannot understand what is going wrong here.

```
data.train <- read.table("Assign2.WineComplete.csv",sep=",",header=T)
# Building decision tree
Train <- data.frame(residual.sugar=data.train$residual.sugar,
                total.sulfur.dioxide=data.train$total.sulfur.dioxide, 
                alcohol=data.train$alcohol,
                quality=data.train$quality)
Pre <- as.formula("pre ~ quality")

fit <- rpart(Pre, method="class",data=Train)
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'pre' not found
```

Comment: You don't need the second or third lines of your code. Just do the `read.table` line then do: `fit <- rpart(pre ~ quality, method="class",data=data.train)`.

Comment: I tried what you asked me to do, but I still get the same error

Comment: Is there a upper/lower case problem here? I see 'Pre' declared but error is about 'pre'.

Comment: No, if instead of all the statements, i just write data.train <- read.table("Assign2.WineComplete.csv",sep=",",header=T) and then fit <- rpart(pre ~ quality, method="class",data=data.train) , i get the same error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't know why @Janos deleted his answer, but it's correct: your data frame `Train` doesn't have a column named `pre`. When you pass a formula and a data frame to a model-fitting function, the names in the formula have to refer to columns in the data frame. Your `Train` has columns called `residual.sugar`, `total.sulfur`, `alcohol` and `quality`. You need to change either your formula or your data frame so they're consistent with each other.

And just to clarify: `Pre` is an object containing a formula. That formula contains a reference to the variable `pre`. It's the latter that has to be consistent with the data frame.

Comment: Well.. I mistakenly deleted his post while trying to edit my comment.. sorry about that @Janos..  i get what you say.. but when building a decision tree using rpart, can you please tell me how the formula should be, the decision tree has to be made only the column "quality". I tried to use the example in R :: fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)

Comment: To use `rpart`, you need a dependent variable: something that is to be predicted or estimated using the independent variables. Which of those in your data frame is the dependent?

Answer (score 13):

This can happen if you don't attach your *dataset*.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got what I was looking for..

```
data.train <- read.table("Assign2.WineComplete.csv",sep=",",header=T)
fit <- rpart(quality ~ ., method="class",data=data.train)
plot(fit)
text(fit, use.n=TRUE)
summary(fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

i use 
    colname(train) = paste("A", colname(train))
and it turns out to the same problem as yours.

I finally figure out that randomForest is more stingy than rpart, it can't recognize the colname with space, comma or other specific punctuation.

paste function will prepend "A" and " " as seperator with each colname.
so we need to avert the space and use this sentence instead:

```
colname(train) = paste("A", colname(train), sep = "")
```

this will prepend string without space.