# eval trouble into R package

Tags: r, eval, environment

I have been making a package to upload to CRAN, but I have a little trouble.

If you go to the website, https://github.com/elflacosebas/migraR, you will find the package.

You can run the example to test it.

The problem comes when I want to avoid the attach and perform the best_migramod function. Then, it will use inside fit_migramod, which uses a class named Migramodel.

You can run the example now without the line codes below:

`colnames(data1) <- c("x","y")`

`attach(data1)`

The error I get says:

`Error in eval(.self$expr, c(as.list(p), as.list(data))) :`
  `object 'x' not finded`

I have tried using attach and detach to solve it into the best_migradmod function but it doesn't work. I understand it is a matter of environment as this post says as well.

[Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463137/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-not-found)

Where shoud I put the attach? or the other operators, or should I modify the data file? or

Thanks a lot for the hint!!

Comment: `attach` is not recommended.  If you want to extract the variables, use `[[` or `$` or using `with`

Comment: in particular not within packages

Comment: akrun yes, but I have check it, but if you see attach is out the package, I have seen the functions but I've been trying in different ways... where to put the [[ $ or with?

Answer (score 0):

In my laptop work the example without the two lines that you mentioned

sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] migraR_0.1.2   devtools_2.2.1 usethis_1.5.1  dplyr_0.8.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        rstudioapi_0.10   magrittr_1.5      tidyselect_0.2.5  pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0
 [7] rlang_0.4.2       tools_3.6.0       pkgbuild_1.0.6    sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0         withr_2.1.2
[13] remotes_2.1.0     ellipsis_0.3.0    rprojroot_1.3-2   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.20     tibble_2.1.3
[19] crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.4.1    purrr_0.3.3       callr_3.3.1       fs_1.3.1          ps_1.3.0
[25] curl_4.0          testthat_2.3.1    memoise_1.1.0     glue_1.3.1        compiler_3.6.0    pillar_1.4.2
[31] backports_1.1.4   desc_1.2.0        prettyunits_1.0.2 pkgconfig_2.0.2

Comment: Could the packages change depending on the configuration of the pc's? that is another question to add to this develop. Thanks Cesc13.